# end tag for "meta" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified

Tags: validation, xslt, xhtml, w3c-validation

I am getting the following errors when I try to validate my contact support page.

And for the life of me I cannot get this page to validate.
Also, I am getting this, which makes no sense at all:

```
Error Line 35, Column 215: end tag for "img" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified

Line 1, Column 112: DTDs other than base allowed only if CONCUR YES or EXPLICIT YES
Line 1, Column 112: DTDs other than base allowed only if CONCUR YES or EXPLICIT YES
…rg/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"><!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1…
✉
Error Line 1, Column 206: DTD did not contain element declaration for document type name
…//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"><html>
✉
A DOCTYPE declares the version of the language used, as well as what the root (top) element of your document will be. For example, if the top element of your document is <html>, the DOCTYPE declaration will look like: "<!DOCTYPE html".

In most cases, it is safer not to type or edit the DOCTYPE declaration at all, and preferable to let a tool include it, or copy and paste it from a trusted list of DTDs.

Error Line 1, Column 207: Missing xmlns attribute for element html. The value should be: http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml
…//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"><html>
✉
Many Document Types based on XML need a mandatory xmlns attribute on the root element. For example, the root element for XHTML might look like:
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

Error Line 3, Column 75: end tag for "meta" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
✉
You may have neglected to close an element, or perhaps you meant to "self-close" an element, that is, ending it with "/>" instead of ">".

Info Line 3, Column 3: start tag was here
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
Error Line 4, Column 59: end tag for "link" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
✉
You may have neglected to close an element, or perhaps you meant to "self-close" an element, that is, ending it with "/>" instead of ">".
```

Here is the source for my page :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
  <xsl:output method="html"
        encoding="ISO-8859-1"
        doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
        doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"
        indent="yes"></xsl:output>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&lt;!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"></xsl:text>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"></link>
<title>Titre</title> 

</head>
    <body>

<img alt="image" style="margin-top:8px;"><xsl:attribute name="src" >images/D.png</xsl:attribute></img>

....
```

Comment: Hm, are you trying to validate this raw XML source as if it was XHTML, or are you trying to validate the resulting XHTML (after the XSLT transformation)?

Answer (score 0):

I see two things.

1. Your output method is `html`, but you're referencing an XML DTD (xhtml). Either change your output method to `xml` or reference an HTML DTD (HTML DTDs are SGML).
2. Since you're outputting the doctype declaration with `xsl:output`, you should remove the doctype declaration you're trying to output with `xsl:text`. You can't have more than one doctype declaration.

Example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output 
        method="html" 
        encoding="ISO-8859-1" 
        doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
        doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd" 
        indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
                <title>Titre</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <img alt="image" style="margin-top:8px;">
                    <xsl:attribute name="src">images/D.png</xsl:attribute>
                </img>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you give me the syntax !

Comment: I added an example. All I did was delete the `xsl:text` and change `method="html"` to `method="xml"`.

Comment: Thanks you but I don't understand why xml,because i want to have An Html page

Comment: Because you're pointing to the XHTML DTD which is XML. Do you want me to update my example with an HTML DTD?

Comment: well I have also this error : Error Line 35, Column 215: end tag for "img" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified

Comment: Do you know how i can fixed !!

Comment: @SamiLi - There's no way to know unless you post a complete example ([MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).